# Java. Как правильно соединять методы?

Tags: java, ооп

Все говорят о том что любой метод должен делать только одно действие быть максимально простым
и понятным.

Лучше много маленьких чем один большой.

Вопрос - как правильней связывать эти методы?

Делать в одном вызов другого или выносить их взаимодействие в отдельный метод который будет этим заниматься?

На пример в классе 4 метода и есть еще пятый который их объединяет или вызывать один в другом. Есть ли какой-то типизированный подход к решению этой ситуации? Как это лучше делать?

Comment: Да, подход есть. Но этот подход очень сильно зависит от контекста.

Comment: А может быть знаете где в сжатом виде можно с этой идеей познакомится? В смысле не книгу целиком а статью или серию туториалов ... Так в ознакомительных целях для начала. Или как это называется чтобы искать по правильным ключевым словам.

Comment: Ваш вопрос очень общий, и дать на него какой-либо (лаконичный) ответ вряд ли получится. То, что Вы спрашиваете, приходит с опытом.

Comment: Хотя... можете почитать что-нибудь по рефакторингу кода. Например, [это](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5011068/) или [это](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5508646/), но это книги.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду образовываться))))